# How to Start New Activity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, audio, stream, radio-button

I am attemptting to start a new activity which "implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener" but everyway that I have tried results in the App crashing. Does anyone have any input??

Comment: what are those every ways you have tried so far?

Comment: startActivity(new Intent("com.somerset.collection.noitcelloc.tesremos.mocp.AUDIORADIOBUTTONACTIVITY"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation shouldn't bother anything. I actually just made an Activity that implements that also. The problem must be in how your stating your activity. You didn't give us much information to work with.
Did you add the Activity to your AndroidManifest.xml file? That's the most common thing.

Comment: Here is my code and I have set the functions correct in the Manifest

Comment: How should I start the Activity? I am using the standard method of startActivity(new Intent("com.somerset.collection.noitcelloc.tesremos.mocp.AUDIORADIOBUTTONACTIVITY"));

Comment: Manifest right here <activity
            android:name=".AudioRadioButtonActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.somerset.collection.noitcelloc.tesremos.moc.AUDIORADIOBUTTONACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: here is my full button Button bAudio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.music);
     bAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent("com.somerset.collection.noitcelloc.tesremos.mocp.AUDIORADIOBUTTONACTIVITY"));
             
           }
      });

Comment: I found the error in my button Not "com.somerset.collection.noitcelloc.tesremos.mocp" but "com.somerset.collection.noitcelloc.tesremos.moc"